Can I configure SOA Gateway on Oracle E-Business Suite 12.1.3 with Oracle Database 12c (12.1.0.2)?
I am currently running Oracle E-Business Suite (EBS) version 12.1.3 with Oracle Database 12c (12.1.0.2) on Oracle Linux 7.2. I need to integrate SOA Gateway with this setup to enable web services for various business processes.
I've reviewed some Oracle documentation and patches, but I'm still uncertain about the compatibility and necessary steps for configuring SOA Gateway in this specific environment.

Is it officially supported to configure SOA Gateway on EBS 12.1.3 with Oracle Database 12c (12.1.0.2)?

If supported, are there specific patches or configurations required to ensure a smooth integration?

What potential issues should I be aware of during this configuration?


I've seen references to patches and certifications for EBS 12.1.3 with later versions of Oracle Database, such as 19c. However, my current setup is specifically with Database 12c (12.1.0.2), and I want to confirm that the integration will work without upgrading the database.
Any detailed guidance or references to official Oracle documentation would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
